# TXMLDocument->ChildNodes->Add() creates unwanted empty xmlns attribute

Tags: xml, c++builder

This is driving me crazy. I need to combine several XML classes into one final document. They are all defined by the Federal government. So after filling out each xml class (created using the XML Data Binding Wizard) with the appropriate values, I need to insert a couple of classes as child nodes. Unfortunately the way I'm doing this creates an empty (and not to federal specifications) xmlns="" attribute. Here's the gist of my code (with non-relevant pieces removed)

```
IRSReturn = new TXMLDocument(GetWindow());
IRSReturn->DOMVendor = GetDOMVendor("MSXML"); // NOT cross platform compatible

IRSReturnRoot = GetReturn(IRSReturn);

IRSReturn->Version = "1.0";
IRSReturn->Encoding = "UTF-8";
IRSReturnRoot->returnVersion = "2015v3.0";
IRSReturnRoot->SetAttribute("xmlns", eReturn_TargetNamespace);
IRSReturnRoot->SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", eReturn_Schema);
IRSReturnRoot->SetAttribute("xmlns:efile", eReturn_TargetNamespace);

IRSReturnHeader = new TXMLDocument(GetWindow());
IRSReturnHeader->DOMVendor = GetDOMVendor("MSXML"); // NOT cross platform compatible

IRSRetHeadRoot = GetReturnHeader(IRSReturnHeader);

// Fill out IRSRetHeadRoot fields ...

IRSReturnRoot->ChildNodes->Add(IRSReturnHeader->DocumentElement);
IRSReturn->XML->Text = FormatXMLData(IRSReturn->XML->Text);
IRSReturn->Active = true;

IRSReturn->SaveToFile("IRSReturnTest.xml");
```

This works perfectly ***except*** that the ReturnHeader child node gets an unwanted xmlns="" attribute added to it like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"? encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Return returnVersion="2015v3.0" xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:efile="http://www.irs.gov/efile">
    <ReturnHeader xmlns="" binaryAttachmentCnt="0">
    // details removed
    </ReturnHeader>
</Return>
```

How can I get rid of the unwanted namespace attribute after adding it, or even better keep the Add() method from adding it in the first place?

(I've tried turning off the doAutoPrefix option with the code below and it doesn't seem to make any difference.)

```
IRSReturn->Options = IRSReturn->Options >> doAutoPrefix;
```

Comment: You need to use `DeclareNamespace()` instead of `SetAttribute()` when adding the namespaces to the root document so it knows about the namespaces and can propagate them to child nodes. But why are you creating and merging two separate documents in the first place? Why is `ReturnHeader` its own document? You should be creating `ReturnHeader` as a child of `Return` to begin with, then it can inherit one of `Return`'s namespaces (you specify the namespace when calling `IXMLNode::AddChild()`. And you should be using `NewXMLDocument()` instead of `new TXMLDocument()`.

Comment: I don't think the XML Data Binding wizard is helping you in this situation.  At the very least, you may need to tweak the generated classes to assign proper namespaces to them. But I really don't think `ReturnHeader` should be its own document to begin with, it should be created as a child of `Return` instead.